# Как сериализовать объект?

Tags: android

как в Android Studio записать JSON в строку?

пробовал так:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("id", "10");
        jsonObject.put("value1", "15");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str = jsonObject.toString();
```

но Studio не видит JSONObject

`import org.json.JSONObject;` дает ошибку

`UPDATE`

решил использовать `GSON`

в gradle подключил

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

сделал по примеру:

```
class MyClass {
    public int id;
    public int value;

    public MyClass(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

String myClassAsJsonString = new Gson().toJson(new MyClass(10, 15));
Gdx.app.log("GSON out ", myClassAsJsonString);
```

в ответ получил:

> GSON out : null

что сделано не правильно?

`UPDATE2`

все заработало,
проблема была в области видимости переменных класса

`UPDATE3`

подскажите почему не сработал первый вариант, и отработал второй?

разве у них не одинаковый доступ к переменным?

1:

```
Object obj = new Object() {
    int id = 10;
    int value = 15;

};

String str = new Gson().toJson(obj);
Gdx.app.log("GSON ", str);
```

> GSON null

2:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int id;
    public int value;

    public MyClass(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

String str = new Gson().toJson(new MyClass(10, 15));
System.out.print("GSON " + str);
```

> GSON {"id":10,"value":15}

Comment: Используйте либы. Например `Gson` от гугла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ответить не хотите? Вопрос вроде востребованный. ))

Comment: `org.json.JSONObject` входит в Android SDK с первой версии. Попробуйте сделать _Build -> Clean Project_, должно помочь. А в остальном, ваш код верен.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а чем пакет `org.json.*` не "либа" для работы с JSON? Встроена в систему, вполне себе для таких случаев как автор пишет. И все верно делает.

Comment: Как известно, пакет `org.json` входит в дистрибутив Android SDK, но он опять же как известно сильно покоцанный и не соответствует официальной версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гораздо проще для таких целей использовать сторонние библиотеки. Стандартная неудобна, слишком многое надо руками делать,  что ведёт к ошибкам, опечаткам etc.

С помощью либы от гугла [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/) всё это делается так:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int id;
    public int value;

    public MyClass(int id, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value
    }
}


String myClassAsJsonString = new Gson().toJson(new MyClass(10, 15));
```

Чтобы её использовать - подключите через `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

Comment: не получилось. обновил вопрос

Comment: @ravend, только что у себя проверил - всё работает. Попробуйте по другому вывести/отключить InstantRun

Comment: InstantRun отключил, вывожу через `System.out.print` эффект тот же.  null возвращается

Comment: @ravend, единственно объяснение которое мне приходит в голову - вы используете LibGdx и оно как-то конфлиткует с Gson. Попробуйте создать пустой андроид проект и в нём это запустить - должно работать. У меня - работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, либы значит проще, говорите :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, конечно) Если `hello world` для либы не работает в живом проекте - это вина проекта, не либы)

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: @ravend, Gson использует рефлексию для получения списка полей класса, объект которого вы ему даёте. Т.к. в первом случае вы ему `Object` даёте, то `Gson` не находит в нём никаких полей (т.к. смотрит на объявление класса, не на конкретный экземпляр анонимного класса как у вас). Вообще должен был получиться пустой объект (`{}`), но, наверное, Gson просто так работает в данном конкретном случае. Надо использовать заранее определённые классы-модели.

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код верный, проверьте настройки проекта, надо выяснить почему

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

не проходит. А должен. Этот пакет является частью `Android Platform`.

Comment: а как проверить настройки, что искать?

Comment: В проекции `Project` внизу смотреть список `External Libraries`. Должен быть в списке `Android API XX Platform`.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у Вас не подключена библиотека.
Есть несколько библиотек. Я лично использую библиотеку от Google - GSON
Если не подключали библиотеку то добавьте в `app/build.gradle`
поле
`dependencies` :
`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'`

подходящую версию выберите сами.

Comment: подключил GSON, но json не получил, дописал вопрос